# How to change the top directory in LTspice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I installed LTspice in `C:\Program Files`, and when I go to "search components", the top directory is `C:\Documents`.

How can I change my top directory?

[image: LTSpice component selection - top directory]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add additional paths/folders/directories by going to `Tools` > `Control Panel`

[image: LTspice XVII Tools Menu]

Then select the `Sym. & Lib. Search Paths` tab.

[image: LTspice XVII Symbol and Library Search Paths]

Since you are trying to add paths to symbols, add the paths in the top textbox:
`Symbol Search Path[*]`

Multiple paths can be separated on new lines, or by semicolons `;` (which will be converted to new lines after closing the window).

If a path does not yet exist (perhaps you made a typo) then LTspice will ask if you want to include them anyway. Note that *if they don't yet exist, they will not show up* in the directory selection drop-down list.

If all goes well, you will see your new paths in the list:

[image: LTspice XVII - Select Component Symbol - Top Directory]

Answer (score 0):

Bort answer is ok, but I wanted to move the primary lib directory to another drive so I don't loose updates between windows installs.

So I make a symlink. This is how you can do it.
Close LTSpice. Rename original lib directory to lib.bak. Start command prompt and to go the lib lib directory - in my case.
Let's say you want to change the directory to D:\Programs\LTspice\lib :

```
c:
cd "C:\Users\user\Documents\LTspiceXVII"
rename lib lib.bak
mklink /J "lib" "D:\Programs\LTspice\lib"
```

You could still add additional directories in control panel if you like according to Bort's answer