# LTspice on MacOS - empty library

Tags: ltspice, osx

On freshly installed LTspice on MacOS I have no libraries. In "Top directory is only `/`, but there is no way to edit this path, also in settings there is no tab described here:

[How to change the top directory in LTspice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399065/how-to-change-the-top-directory-in-ltspice)

[image]

Updated settings screens:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

maybe, there will be a way to edit configuration file manually, bu I don't know the key:

```
$ plutil -p Library/Preferences/LTC.LTspice.plist 
{
  "AllowShortedCompPins" => 0
  "AutoDotRawDeletion" => 1
  "DampInductors" => 1
  "GridColor" => 9868950
  "InActiveAxisColor" => 9868950
  "NetlistEditorColor0" => 0
  "NetlistEditorColor1" => 32512
  "NetlistEditorColor2" => 16711680
  "NetlistEditorColor3" => 155
  "NetlistEditorColor4" => 16777215
  "NoJFETtempAdjIsr" => 0
  "NSNavLastRootDirectory" => "~/Documents"
  "NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForOpenMode" => "{712, 448}"
  "PlotLineThickness" => 1
  "PrintListing" => 0
  "RadianMeasure" => 0
  "RandomizeSeed" => 0
  "ReverseMouseWheelScroll" => 0
  "RoboMouse" => 1
  "SaveDeviceCurrents" => 1
  "SaveOneCurrentPerDevice" => 0
  "SaveSubcircuitDeviceCurrents" => 0
  "SaveSubcircuitNodeVoltages" => 0
  "SchematicColor0" => 16711680
  "SchematicColor1" => 16711680
  "SchematicColor2" => 16711680
  "SchematicColor3" => 16711680
  "SchematicColor4" => 12648447
  "SchematicColor5" => 0
  "SchematicColor6" => 0
  "SchematicColor7" => 0
  "SchematicColor8" => 13107200
  "SchematicColor9" => 16711680
  "SchematicColor10" => 65535
  "SchematicColor11" => 0
  "SchematicColor12" => 12632256
  "SchPenWidth" => 1
  "Solver" => 0
  "TSKtrtol" => 2
  "WaveColor0" => 0
  "WaveColor1" => 11513775
  "WaveColor2" => 65280
  "WaveColor3" => 16711680
  "WaveColor4" => 255
  "WaveColor5" => 11513600
  "WaveColor6" => 16711935
  "WaveColor7" => 8421504
  "WaveColor8" => 32768
  "WaveColor9" => 11468800
  "WaveColor10" => 32943
  "WaveColor11" => 8388736
  "WaveColor12" => 128
  "WaveColor13" => 44975
}
```

Comment: `there is no tab described here` .... why don't you post a picture of that also?

Comment: `there is no tab described here` .... why don't you post a picture of that also?

Comment: I don't have the Mac version, but if there's no tab like the one in the linked answer, you can't edit them from the GUI. You could try to add `SymbolSearchPath=/path/to/one;/path/to/two` and `LibrarySearchPath=/another/path;/yet/another/one` and see if it works. If this one still doesn't, it most probably means you cannot do it in Mac. Is there anything about this in the `Help`?

Comment: The edit box `Top directory` is not editable.

Comment: This won't help solve your current issue, but as an LTSpice and Mac user, I'll say that running it through wine provides the same performance without the multitude of missing features in the Mac version.

Comment: I suspect it is a bug and should be sent to the developers. I'm observing this behaviour under macOS Mojave, too. --
Christoph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Top directory` has no effect. There are all the libraries, but are hidden, because the problem is in combination of dark theme in MacOS.

[image]
[image]