# How to change the top directory in LTspice for Mac?

Tags: ltspice

As [LTspice on MacOS - empty library](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404331/ltspice-on-macos-empty-library) points out, there doesn't seem to be any way to change the top directory in LTspice for Mac.

[How to change the top directory in LTspice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399065/how-to-change-the-top-directory-in-ltspice) shows a screen with a control panel tab to change the search paths on a PC, but that tab is missing from the Mac version:

[image: LTspice for Mac Control Panel]

I tried adding a symbolic link from the Mac LTspice Library folder to my folder, but LTspice doesn't seem to understand symbolic links.

Is there any way to change the top directory on LTspice for Mac? Or to have LTspice search my directory as well as its own library?

I'm especially interested in LTspice finding the autogenerated symbols for my own hierarchical schematics. Thanks!

Comment: Try the workaround in [this comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404331/ltspice-on-macos-empty-library#comment994901_404331). If it still doesn't work, best write to the authors, see `Help > About`. The autogenerated symbols should be in the default path, under `[AutoGenerated]`. Don't forget that the symbols/lubraries have a copy residing in the equivalent of the `My Documents` folder, and if you plan on modifying them (not recommended), that's where you should be looking for, not in the equivalent of the `Program Files`.

Comment: "a copy residing in the equivalent of the My Documents folder"... LTspice saves my autogenerated symbol in ~/Documents/LTspice. However, that folder is not on the LTSpice search path, and contains only my data, not the LTspice libraries.

Comment: Isn't there any folder `LTspiceXVII`? If not, it could be that the Mac version behaves differently, in which case I can't help you. You can also try using an emulator for the Windows version.